# A Pick function $f$ is either real constant or $f(\mathbb{H})\subseteq \mathbb{H}$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Definition**: A Pick function $f$ is a holomorphic function on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$ for which $\Im f(z)\geq 0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{H}$.

I read a statement, though no proof included, that

> A Pick function $f$ is either real constant or $f(\mathbb{H})\subseteq \mathbb{H}$. In particular, if $f$ is non-zero Pick function with no zeroes in $\mathbb{H}$, then $-1/f$ is Pick function.

How to prove the first sentence? Should I use Integral Representation of Pick functions? For the last one, I think one could do as follows, which I need you to confirm. Assume $f$ is non-zero Pick function with no zeroes in $\mathbb{H}$. Then, since $\Im f>0$, we get $\Im(-\overline{f})>0$, and so $\Im(-1/f)=|f|^{-2}\Im(-\overline{f})>0$. Then $\Im(-1/f)\geq 0$, which shows that $-1/f$ is Pick function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Im f$ is a real harmonic function, so if it has local minima or maxima it is constant; since $\Im f \ge 0$, a point where $\Im f(w)=0$ is a local minimum, hence its existence implies $\Im f$ constant, hence $f$ constant; so if $f$ non-constant, $\Im f(z) >0$ for all $\Im z>0$ or equivalently, $f(\mathbb H) \subset \mathbb H$

Part 2 is correct as $\Im \frac{1}{f}=-\frac{\Im f}{|f|^2}$

Comment: Could you explain me why you start saying $\Im f(w)=0$ for some $w$; i.e. what's the behind of it, when there is nowhere in the statement (hypothesis) we could assume that way? I mean, how do you know the existence of $w$ so that $\Im f(w)=0$?

Comment: The hypothesis is $\Im f(z) \ge 0$ for $\Im z >0$; we have two cases - either $\Im f(z) >0$ for all $\Im z>0$ or there exists $w \in \mathbb H$ st $\Im f(w)=0$ and that leads to $f$ constant, hence either $f$ constant or $f(\mathbb H) \subset \mathbb H$ so done (also added a little more detail in the answer as I think I get your confusion)

Comment: OK. Assuming that $\Im f(w)=0$ for some $w$. Where did you get it from that it implies that $\Im f$ is constant? Is it due to Integral Representation for Pick functions?

Comment: No - it is due to the fact that $\Im f$ is real harmonic so it cannot have local minima or maxima unless constant (assume $\Im f(w)=0$ then $0=\Im f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\Im f(w+re^{it})dt$ for small $r>0$ st $D_w(r) \subset \mathbb H$ hence since the integral is zero and the integrand non-negative, it must be zero, so $\Im f=0, z \in  D_w(r)$ and then the usual connectivity argument, shows $\Im f=0$ everywhere in $\mathbb H$ etc)

Comment: Okay, I haven't studied much about the harmonic functions. I think I'll use the alternate method, using the representation, as I made another new [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815700/) (where I took the imaginary part of both sides of $0=f(w)=\int \textrm{Representation}$, and $w=x+iy$). Thanks for your useful answer, it made me understand better.

Comment: that is of course another way to do it but imho it is a complicated way in the sense that it depends on Herglotz/Pick representation which is a non-trivial result, while the result about harmonic functions is very basic (essentially a variant of maximum modulus theorem applied for both minimum and maximum now as the function is real)